# Find a string and create a variable with regex

Tags: php, regex, variables

I grab the source code of a website with file_get_contents().
Inside this code, i try to detect this king string and put the content of idDM in a variable.

```
'idDM':'x1mi7f7'
```

For example, here, $idDM will be equal to x1mi7f7, but the string can be :

```
'idDM':'xxxxxxx'
```

And the variable will be xxxxxxx.

I know o have to use REGEX for that. For now, I just manage to find if there is IdDM, but not to recover its contents.

Any advice ? Thanks.

Comment: If the file you get has a Json-like format, it is probably easier to use json-decode (after little modification if needed).

Answer (score 3):

Use the following regex:

```
'idDM'\s*:\s*'([^']+)'
```

**Explanation:**

- `'idDM'` - match the literal string `'idDM'` (with the quotes)
- `\s*` - match one or more whitespace character
- `:` - match a literal colon character
- `\s*` - match one or more whitespace character
- `'([^']+)'` - match (and capture) everything that's inside single-quotes

**Usage:**

```
$str = "foo bar 'idDM':'x1mi7f7' more baz";

if (preg_match("/'idDM'\s*:\s*'([^']+)'/", $str, $matches)) {
    $idDM = $matches[1];
}

var_dump($idDM); // => string(7) "x1mi7f7"
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/133273)

Comment: Thanks fo your answer and the explanation. It's really perfect !

Comment: @artmees: That's not really needed in this case as the variable will get initialized inside the `if` block if a match is found. Plus, the `idDM` part seems to be constant, so I don't see the reason to use variable-variables here.

Comment: @AmalMurali thanks i thought he needed to add it to a variable :D mybad